# C: One error In strcpy function and cannot find it

Tags: c, strcpy

I know that this strcpy function below is incorrect, but I cannot seem to figure out the one or two things I need to change to fix it. Any help would be greatly appreciated as I am completely stuck on this:

```
void strcpy(char *destString, char *sourceString)
{
       char *marker, *t;
       for(marker = sourceString, t = destString; *marker; marker++, t++)
       *t = *marker;
}
```

Comment: `while (*dststring++ = *srcstring++) {;}`

Comment: You wrote 'clever' code with an inappropriate loop construct and comma operators.  Unsurprisingly, it does not work:(

Comment: set null-terminator.

Comment: It doesn't actually copy the string correctly, I have encountered this problem before and my teacher told us that there was one simple change needed to be made, but I can't figure out what it is.

Comment: If you are referring to a null terminator in the for loop, I was told that the *marker is equivalent to it already.

Comment: Add `*t='\0';` before the end of function.

Comment: Problem is that you exit the loop and the function before the copying the null termination. For future reference, please see how to provide [mcve] to make things easier for everyone when asking a question.

Comment: Did you make any attempts to debug this ?

Comment: Alright I see the error in the code now thank you very much everyone. Yes, I did make attempts to debug this code but it ended up in me rewriting it and getting it wrong previously, so that is why I was stuck today.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well it depends on your environment..

For example I see a few things I don't like:

- You do not check for input parameters to be `!= NULL`. This will cause a `*0` access
- I see you are not terminating your string with the `'\0'` character (or `0`).. So, after the loop (please intent.) add `*t = 0;`

Comment: Do not ever use `NULL` for null termination; it's a null pointer constant. Use integer zero `0` or `'\0'`.

Comment: Yeah you are right, I updated the comment.. I usually don't have anything defined in my environment :)

Comment: I understood what he meant by it and used the null operator '\0', Thank you for the help.

Comment: yep sry, new to all this :|

Comment: @MichaelWalz that is about input parameter... so char pointer comparison

Comment: @Kons sorry, you are right. BTW the check for NULL as input parameter is not requested by `strcpy`.

Comment: @MichaelWalz well not requested doesn't mean not useful... :)

Answer (score 1):

*strcpy()* is a predefined function and you are trying to create your own **strcpy** function. so, when you compile your program, you are getting **conflicting types** error. So, first **rename** your function name.

Comment: But for that we've to import string.h header .How compiler will know that this is inbuilt function without importing header file ?

Comment: This is a comment, not an answer. Delete it before it' gets downvoted.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to implement your own `strcpy()`, then i would suggest to implement `strncpy()`. It will copy at-most `n-1` bytes from `source null-terminated character array` to `destination character array` and also add `null character` at the end of the `destination character array`.

```
void strcpy(char *dest, const char *src, size_t n)
{
   if ((dest == NULL) || (src == NULL))
       return;
   int i;
   for(i=0; i<(n-1) && src[i]; i++)
       dest[i] = src[i];
   dest[i]='\0';
}
```

It wouldn't let `buffer overflow`.

Note -     My implementation is different from standard library `strncpy()` implementation. The standard library function strncpy() copies at most n bytes of src. If there is no null byte among the first n bytes of src, the string placed in dest will not be null-terminated.

> I know that this strcpy function below is incorrect, but I cannot seem to figure out the one or two things I need to change to fix it.

You only need to add null character at the end of destination array.

```
void strcpy(char *destString, char *sourceString)
{
   char *marker, *t;
   for(marker = sourceString, t = destString; *marker; marker++, t++)
       *t = *marker;
   *t='\0';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a very simple aproach:

```
void copy(char * src, char * dst){
    while(*src != '\0'){
        *dst = *src;
        src++;
        dst++;
    }
    *dst = '\0';
}

int main(int argc, char** argv){
    char src [] = "hello";
    char dst [] = "----";

    copy(src, dst);
    printf("src: %s\n", src);
    printf("dst: %s\n", dst );

}
```

It's more or less like wildplasser comment. First you iterate over the src pointer. In c, if you have '\0' (in a well formed string) then you can exit because it is the final character. Ok, you iterate over the src pointer and assign the value of src (*src) to the value of dst (*dst) and then you only have to increase both pointers...

It's all

Answer (score 0):

A very easy strcpy function would be:

```
int strcpy(char *dest,char *source)
{
if (source==NULL)
{
 printf("The source pointer is NULL");
 return 0;
}
if (dest==NULL)
{
 dest=(char*)malloc((strlen(source)+1)*sizeof(char));
}
int i;
for (i=0;source[i]!='\0';i++)
 {
  dest[i]=source[i];
 }
dest[i]='\0';
return 1;
}
```

You should have no problem copying strings this way. Always use indexes instead of pointer operations, it's easier imo.

If you use an IDE, you should learn to use the debug function to discover the errors and problems, usually when you deal with strings one of the most common RUNTIME problems is the lack of a '\0', which automatically make your string functions go to memory zones where they shouldn`t be.